# PSQL avoid insert failing because a trigger failed

Tags: postgresql, trigger, insert, error-handling

I want to put a trigger on a table, the code itself could work sometimes, while sometimes it might fail unexpectedly.

So I need the data to get inserted on the table regardless if one of its triggers (ON INSERT) failed. Is this possible?

Is there some error handling at the trigger to just don't do anything if an error is encountered, so that it will return control to the original INSERT clause?

In summary, my goal is that if a trigger on INSERT fails, the original INSERT proceeds either way

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING

Answer (score 0):

> my goal is that if a trigger on INSERT fails, the original INSERT proceeds either way

Presumably the trigger was put there for a *Reason*.
Just trying to "get round" that Reason is going to get you Bad Data in your table(s) and that's just going to give you *more* headaches further down the line.
Don't do it.

Find out *why* the trigger is rejecting your data and then, either

- fix your data so that it works *with* the trigger,
- fix the trigger itself!

Comment: As to the latter: you can trap errors in PL/pgSQL with a `BEGIN ... EXCEPTION ... END` block. That way, an error does not have to terminate the transaction.